# Detecting employee designation from text using ner/nlp

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am very new to the field of NLP and i am interested in detecting the position/designation/role along with their name, email,phone number etc. I tried using stanford NLP to detect names from text. Email and phone number parsing seems pretty straightforward. I am unable to however detect the designation from a given text.

For instance, here are some sample examples of text

1)Medical Superintendent,Dr. A.B. Ahmad,example1@example.com
Name:Dr. A.B. Ahmad, Email: example1@example.com

2)Sub-Dean Academics    Prof. S. Antony  example2@example.com
Name:Prof. S. Antony, Email: example2@example.com

3)Sub-Dean Academics & PG-Cell & Surg. Discipline Resident Trg. Programe,Mr. Sandeep
Name: Mr. Sandeep, Email: none

4)Director, Networking, Robert Adams, example3@example.com,9900131213
Name: Robert Adams, Email: example3@example.com, Phone: 9900131213

I am not interested in any regex matching algorithms since the nature of the text is non deterministic. What i am interested in knowing is how do i go about extracting the above designtations from the text. Any solution even beyond stanford NLP like using nltk, lingpipe etc is fine. If i am using stanford NLP, how do i build a training model for the same with a different entity type like "POSITION" or "DESIGNATION" and how do i include this model along with my other models(i am running stanford NLP in server mode).

Comment: You will need to train your own NER model, introducing your own tag 'DESIGNATION' in your training set. Take a look at their documentaion. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a

Comment: to train stanford parser for `designation` you need lot of training data for that you have to collect larger data because small amount of data might not give you correct data

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below file(designation.rules.txt)

```
ENV.defaultStringPatternFlags = 2

ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

$Designation = (
  /CFO/|
  /Director/| 
  /CEO/|
  /Chief/| 
  /Executive/| 
  /Officer/|
  /Vice/| 
  /President/|
  /Senior/|
  /Financial/
)

ENV.defaults["ruleType"] = "tokens"
ENV.defaults["stage"] = 1
{
  pattern: ( $Designation ), 
  action: ( Annotate($0, ner, "DESIGNATION")) 
}

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 2
{
  ruleType: "tokens",
  pattern: ( ( [ { ner:PERSON } ]) /has/ ([ { ner:DESIGNATION } ]+) ),
  result: Format("hasDesignation(%s,%s)",$1.word, Join(" ",$2.word))
}
```

And Use the below Java file to generate

```
package org.itcookies.nlpdemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

/**
 * Demo illustrating how to use TokensRegexAnnotator
 */
public class TokensRegexAnnotatorDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out;

    String rules;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      rules = args[0];
    } else {
      rules = "org/itcookies/nlp/rules/designation.rules.txt";
    }
    if (args.length > 2) {
      out = new PrintWriter(args[2]);
    } else {
      out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    }

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregexdemo");
    properties.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.tokensregexdemo", "edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexAnnotator");
    properties.setProperty("tokensregexdemo.rules", rules);
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
    Annotation annotation;
    if (args.length > 1) {
      annotation = new Annotation(IOUtils.slurpFileNoExceptions(args[1]));
    } else {
      annotation = new Annotation("John is CEO of ITCookies");
    }

    pipeline.annotate(annotation);

    // An Annotation is a Map and you can get and use the various analyses individually.
    out.println();
    // The toString() method on an Annotation just prints the text of the Annotation
    // But you can see what is in it with other methods like toShorterString()
    out.println("The top level annotation");
    out.println(annotation.toShorterString());
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
      // NOTE: Depending on what tokensregex rules are specified, there are other annotations
      //       that are of interest other than just the tokens and what we print out here
      for (CoreLabel token:sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        // Print out words, lemma, ne, and normalized ne
        String word = token.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class);
        String lemma = token.get(CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation.class);
        String pos = token.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
        String ne = token.get(CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
        String normalized = token.get(CoreAnnotations.NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
        if(ne.equals("DESIGNATION"))
            out.println("token: " + "word="+word + ", lemma="+lemma + ", pos=" + pos + ", ne=" + ne + ", normalized=" + normalized);
      }
    }
    out.flush();
  }

}
```

And below is the output

```
The top level annotation
[Text=John is CEO of ITCookies Tokens=[John-1, is-2, CEO-3, of-4, ITCookies-5] Sentences=[John is CEO of ITCookies]]
token: word=CEO, lemma=CEO, pos=NNP, ne=DESIGNATION, normalized=null
```